# Branches and trunk in SVN

Tags: svn, abap, sap-basis

I am an SAP developer and in the SAP landscape, we have a Development server (DEV), a Quality server for testing (QAS) and the Production server (PROD).

Developers develop their programs in DEV and then transport it to QAS. In QAS, testers test the program and then transport it to PROD. Later it is deployed to the client from PROD.

I am new to using SVN and was wondering if and how the SAP landscape is analogous to the trunk/ branches/ tags.

Answer (score 2):

They are unrelated for the most part, unless you find that several versions of your code can be making its way from DEV to TEST to PROD at the same time.  In that case, you'll have several branches in flight at once.

"trunk" is really just a special branch.  You can choose to mandate that trunk always contain the latest code merged from all branches.  It acts as the template for all subsequent branches.  If not, you just create one branch from another and merge to keep in synch.

Tags are used to create a read-only, labeled version of code that goes to production.  I'd create a tagged branch from the code that makes it to PROD.  You can always get it back that way.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing in common. Branches are a way to develop new features without disturbing the main line of development, or to maintain older versions of a project in parallel to developing newer versions. I suggest you read the freely available [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html).